# How to reset iOS Maps data

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

Whenever I use maps to get directions to any destination, Maps notes that I have to go over a toll road (denoted with a small € symbol). Except: I live in the Netherlands and we have no toll roads.
Absolutely no road I take should be a toll road, but Maps thinks they are. It even helps by saying "Toll required".

Is there a way to reset my Maps data?

I've had this problem on an iOS 9 iPhone 4S, and I've restored a backup from that device to an iOS 10 iPhone 6s, both show the same toll roads. Every highway or fast lane route is denoted as a toll road.

Possibly related, while navigating, iOS will commonly add extra names to the proncuation.
So for instance "Karel de Groote laan" is pronounced "Karel de-yipiyajeej-laan". Whenever it mispronounces a street name, it always add "yipiyajeej"

Screenshot of route on iOS:
[image: Route on iOS with toll. This is wrong.]

Screenshot of route on macOS:
[image: Same route on macOS without toll. This is correct.]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a problem with your iOS as much as it is Apple's map data, unless of course this issue doesn't happen with other iDevices. The best way to correct an issue with Apple's map data however, is to click on the information button in the maps app, then click on "Report an Issue" and you can explain the issue there so Apple can fix it in future iOS releases.

[image: Where is "Report an Issue" you may ask?]

Comment: I'm pretty sure my girlfriends Maps doesn't show the same route as being a toll route. I'll check later today.
Edit: When I use Maps.app on macOS, it _does not_ show as being a toll route.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure what that issue is then if it's just your device..